# I need to write a query to list all employees and the number of subordinates they have

Tags: sql, oracle

Employees with no subordinates should be listed as having zero subordinates should also be displayed by this query.
I can currently return all employees with subordinates, but I can't seem to display employees with zero subordinates.

Here is the code so far:

```
SELECT s.empno, s.ename, COUNT(*) as "Num_subordinates"
FROM emp e
JOIN emp s ON s.empno=e.super 
GROUP BY s.empno, s.ename;
```

Answer (score 4):

The only missing in your statement is to use `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`. You also need to specify the `ID` instead of `*` when counting in `LEFT JOIN` so you will not yield `1` on the `COUNT()` if the employee don't have subordinate.

```
SELECT e.empno, e.ename, COUNT(s.empno) as "Num_subordinates"
FROM   emp e
       LEFT JOIN emp s ON s.empno = e.super 
GROUP  BY e.empno, e.ename
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Try this, you need to group the records using `e` not `s`. and counting `COUNT(s.empno)`.

Comment: @Bohemian yeah right. I was looking at the `GROUP BY` clause and forget to change also on the `SELECT`..

Comment: On second thoughts I think it was correct and the group by is wrong - he needs a right join: s = super, not subordinate. Ps group by 1, 2 would have been right first time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

Assuming that data is similar to the following

```
| EMPNO |     ENAME |  SUPER |
------------------------------
|     1 |  Manager1 | (null) |
|     2 | Employee1 |      1 |
|     3 | Employee2 |      1 |
|     4 | Employee3 |      1 |
|     5 |  Manager2 | (null) |
|     6 | Employee5 |      5 |
|     7 | Employee6 | (null) |
```

A version with a subquery

```
SELECT e.empno, 
       e.ename, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM emp 
         WHERE super = e.empno) "Num_subordinates"
  FROM emp e;
```

A version with a `JOIN`. You have to use `LEFT JOIN` since `INNER JOIN` filters out necessary rows and as JW correctly pointed out you need to `COUNT` on `s.empno` rather then `*`.

```
SELECT e.empno,
       e.ename,
       COUNT(s.empno) "Num_subordinates"
  FROM emp e LEFT JOIN emp s
    ON s.super = e.empno
 GROUP BY e.empno, e.ename
 ORDER BY e.empno
```

Output for both queries

```
| EMPNO |     ENAME | NUM_SUBORDINATES |
----------------------------------------
|     1 |  Manager1 |                3 |
|     2 | Employee1 |                0 |
|     3 | Employee2 |                0 |
|     4 | Employee3 |                0 |
|     5 |  Manager2 |                1 |
|     6 | Employee5 |                0 |
|     7 | Employee6 |                0 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/447c0/22)** (for both queries)

Comment: This doesn't work. THe only difference with this code is it returns an extra row with null for empno and ename, and 1 for subordinate number

Comment: @user2407714 See the updated answer. If your data is different then please consider to post sample data in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

A few solutions for you problem:

1) grouped auto-join:

```sql
SELECT s.empno, s.ename, COUNT(*) as "Num_subordinates"
FROM emp e RIGHT JOIN emp s ON s.empno=e.super 
GROUP BY s.empno, s.ename;
```

2) left join with aggregate subordinate counts:

```sql
SELECT s.*, c.num_subordinates as "Num_subordinates"
FROM emp s LEFT JOIN (SELECT super AS empno, COUNT(*) FROM emp GROUP BY super) AS c
  ON c.empno = s.empno;
```

or using CTE:

```
WITH c AS (SELECT super AS empno, COUNT(*) FROM emp GROUP BY super)
SELECT s.*, c.num_subordinates as "Num_subordinates"
FROM emp s LEFT JOIN c
  ON c.empno = s.empno;
```

3) using scalar sub-query:

```
SELECT s.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp WHERE super=s.empno) AS "Num_subordinates"
FROM emp s;
```